# Can't fetch channels from Twilio chat client

Tags: vue.js, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm using Twilio to add in app feature in an application ,
when method "initializeClient" is called , it returns this error in the console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwZ77.png)

I understand that it tries to read properties of nonexisted property,
then when i refresh the code in editor or reload using (ctrl+s) it works fine and fetches the channel and everything work fine

what can i do to make it work correctly at the first time ?

the full method

```
async initializeClient(token) {
      const client = await new Chat.Client(token);
      console.log('Client');
      console.log(client);
      
      let mx = max(this.authUser.id, this.otherUser.id);
      let mn = min(this.authUser.id, this.otherUser.id);

      console.log('Before getting the channel');
      
      this.channel = await client.getChannelByUniqueName(
          `${mn}-${mx}`
      );
      
      console.log('After getting the channel');
      console.log(this.channel);

      client.on("tokenAboutToExpire", async () => {
          const token = await this.fetchToken();
          client.updateToken(token);
      });
      this.channel.on("messageAdded", message => {
          console.log('message added');
          this.messages.push(message);
      });
    }
```

when i log the client object in the console first it don't contain the channels property which contains the field that causes the error , and after refreshing the client object contains the channels property